# How can I compute the area between two cdfs in R?

Tags: r, statistics, area, ecdf

I have two cdfs plots as shown below and I need to compute the area between two curves.
[image]
So, the red one can be either completely below green one or completely above it or crossing the green one as shown in the image. For the case when two plots are completely separated, I suppose the area can be obtained using below code:

```
ecdf_diff <- function(t) ecdf_x(t) - ecdf_y(t)

# Integrate the difference between the ECDFs over the range of the data
area <- integrate(ecdf_diff, min(min(x, y)), max(max(x, y)))
```

However, for the case of two plots crossing each other, I need to compute the top part and bottom part (shown by arrows) separately. So two values (one for top and one for bottom) I need to report. Is there any way to do this in R?

Comment: Are you sure you need to compute the area between two CDFs? That is quite unusual. Remember that CDFs are already the integral of the density functions. Are you perhaps trying to calculate the distances mentioned in this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/299391/11849)?

Comment: Why not integrate `abs(ecdf_x(t) - ecdf_y(t))`?

Comment: @Roland yes I need to compute the area between two curves. As I said I need two separated measurement for each part. I searched a lot to find the solution for this but mostly there is solution when only one value is computed.

Comment: I still don’t understand why you need this for CDFs but this is simple undergrad-level maths. The first step is calculating the intersection point of the curves.